# Add smtp Proxy Addresses from users listed in a text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a simple script to add Proxy Addresses to the AD field using PowerShell.

I was able to get it working using this, but now I am at a roadblock on how I can do this importing the usernames from a text file.

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username'
Set-AdUser $Username -add @{ProxyAddresses = "smtp:$Username@example.com,smtp:$Username@marketing.example.com" -split ","}
```

What I want to do now is instead of prompting for a username to be entered I just want to have a text file with username like this.

Text File Of Usernames: These will all be on a separate line. I am not sure how to format that way on here.

```
jallen
sdiggs
gdavis
mhyde
twhite
```

I am confused how to go forward with this. To my understanding I want to use Get-Content to create the username array and then for each line in the text file add the proxy addresses.

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username'
Set-AdUser $Username -add @{ProxyAddresses = "smtp:$Username@example.com,smtp:$Username@marketing.example.com" -split ","}
```

I want to remove the need for user input and import the username variables from a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the txt file with each user in a new line as shown in your question, you're right, you can use `Get-Content` to read your file then you need to loop over each line:

```bash
(Get-Content path\to\yourfile.txt).Trim() | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Set-AdUser $_ -Add @{ ProxyAddresses = "smtp:$_@example.com,smtp:$_@marketing.example.com".Split(",") }
    }
    catch {
        # can do error handling here
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```

The use of `Trim()` in this example is so it removes any excess of white space from the beginning and end of all lines.

Comment: I think you will need to cast the array to `[string[]]` (Strongly typed and IEnumerable)

Comment: @Theo no, no need to. It works as is